# About how keyboardview adapts to talkback

Tags: android, keyboard, accessibilityservice

talkback will select a View to select and draw a green box and then read the contentDescription property, but if you use the keyboardview to customize the keyboard, the keyboard is a complete View, how can talkback select each key and read the key What about the contentDescription attribute?

Answer (score 0):

KeyboardView isn't used by anyone.  It's deprecated in modern Android.  Even before it was deprecated, no serious keyboard used it as it was too restrictive of advanced funtionality.  It was only ever used by people writing example keyboard apps, or as a basic UI for people who were writing a keyboard as a way to test other functionality and wanted a quick UI (for example, if you were really writing an autocorrect algorithm and wanted to write a quick test app).  Not even Google's keyboard (GBoard or LatinIME) use it.

What do keyboard use?  Anything they want, generally one or more custom views.  So how those custom views will interact with accessability functionality like TalkBack is anyone's guess.

However if you really want to look into how KeyboardView works, the code is at https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.java  It appears to use  mAccessibilityManager.sendAccessibilityEvent(event); to send an event whenever it shows a key preview (the long press popup of a character).